# PostgreSQL : set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am new to PostgreSQL and was trying to return result of dynamic query using functions where i am not aware of table and column name in advance. (not all columns).

To achieve this i have written below function however While executing  i am getting  error message. Would appreciate if someone can help me fix this.

```
 ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
      Where: PL/pgSQL function dis.fetch_relationals(bigint,character varying) line 19 at RETURN QUERY
```

There are two input parameters for this function.

**refid -** Based on this i will find out table name and column that need to be fetched.

**reflabel -** Second column that needs to be fetched from same table that we retrieved using first parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fetch_relationals(refid bigint, reflabel character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $functionxx$    
    DECLARE         
     refCol character varying(100);
     tblname character varying(100);
     query varchar;
    begin
        select distinct  colDetails.col_nam, tbldetails.tbl_nam  INTO  refCol, tblname
        from public.rdm_tbl_col_dtl as colDetails 
        inner join public.rdm_tbl tbldetails on colDetails.rtc_rdm_id = tbldetails.id_rdm
        where id_rtc = refId;
        raise notice 'Column Name: %', refCol;      
        tblname:= CONCAT('public.', tblname);
        raise notice 'Table Name : %', tblname;
        query:= 'SELECT ' || refCol || ',' || reflabel ||  ' FROM ' || tblname ;
       raise notice 'tblname: %', tblname;
       raise notice 'Query: %', query;
       RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;                     
    END;       
$functionxx$
;
```

**Logs:**

```
00000: Column Name: ent_type
00000: Table Name : public.business_type
00000: tblname: public.business_type
00000: Query: SELECT ent_type,bus_type FROM public.business_type
```

**Function Call**

```
 SELECT public.fetch_relationals(31, 'bus_type');
```

Comment: Print out the SQL being executed and include that in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank for prompt response. I have added required information

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM public.fetch_relationals(31, 'bus_type');` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV  Sorry for late reply. However that didn't help either

Comment: Okay, then perhaps `CALL public.fetch_relationals(31, 'bus_type');` even though it does not look right ?